# integrate html into django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In my django model I have to store html data as string like

```
 item = RocketuItem(text=text, page_url=url, page_number=page_number, page_down=page_down)
```

and text =

```
 <section> <h2>Object-oriented Python and Beginner Django</h2> <ul>
```

When i pull this in template i use ..

```
{% for page in pages %}
<div>{{ page.page_url|safe }}</div>>
<div>
{{ page.text|safe }}
```

I m using safe as it dosent display $lt etc [basically '<' gets converted to &lt if i dont use it]
This is wht i see at output on the page

```
 <section> <h2>Object-oriented Python and Beginner Django</h2> <ul>
```

What i really want is for the code fro 'text' to be a part of the div so that it well get that formatting and show..

```
Object-oriented Python and Beginner Django
```

How do i do that ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `safe` filter should be enough to render the text as html in recent versions of `Django`. Try using:

```
{% autoescape off %} {{ content }} {% end autoescape %}
```

tags and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

`{% autoescape off %}{{ page.text }}{% endautoescape %}`

Autoescape [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape)